# Excel 2010 copy/paste on worksheet changes another worksheet in same place

Tags: excel-2010

Hi I have a weird problem in excel 2010.

I have set up a series of pages to print on multiple worksheets.

I'm having a problem when I format one of the worksheets using copy/paste or format painter.

The changes are being replicated in the other worksheets on the same row/column.

Has anyone had a similar experience?

or have I found an undocumented feature ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which changes excatly are replicated - data or formats or both?

Formats:

you might have multiple worksheets selected.

there might be conditional formatting.

Data:

you might have multiple worksheets selected.

there might be formulars, which reffer to the same source

Comment: It is both the formats and if i inesrt/delete cells then the same cells are replicated.

Comment: you might have multiple worksheets selected - otherwise you need to provide more information on your data, so that it is possible to replicate this behaviour

Comment: Well asked Jock. I was selecting multiple worksheets for the printing, and not releasing the selection after the print